# Using Fluent Wait When Finding List WebElements

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-automation-framework, eclipse

I have a fluent wait class that works pretty well for locating my page elements, however, when I am locating elements for lists I don't appear to be using the same wait.  I currently need to add sleeps in my page elements that are used to create lists and then make a selection from that list.
How can I leverage my fluent wait class with my lists?

here is an example of a web element and a list:

```
 import com.xxx.utils.fluentWait;

public class FormBuilderPageElements extends fluentWait {

    public FormBuilderPageElements(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
        // Cancel confirm Submission
    By cancelConfirmSubmission = By.cssSelector("button[data-test-id='confirmation-cancel-prompt']");

    public WebElement cancelConfirmSubmission() {

        return this.waitUntil(cancelConfirmSubmission); 
    }

    // Used to locate and click on TABS, which one is determined by the number of the
    // cssSelectors viewed in the console for that element.
    public void clickATab(int whichOne) throws InterruptedException {
        List<WebElement> allTextFields = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[data-test-id='tab-content']"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(allTextFields.get(whichOne)).click().perform();
        Thread.sleep(150);
    }
```

This is what my fluent wait looks like:

```
    package com.xxx.web_form;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;

abstract class fluentWait {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    FluentWait<WebDriver> fluentWait;

    protected fluentWait(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(this.driver);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected WebElement waitUntil(By elementToWaitFor, int timeout, int pollTimeout) {
        fluentWait.withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        fluentWait.pollingEvery(pollTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        fluentWait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
        fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToWaitFor));
        fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[class='ui active loader loader']")));
        return driver.findElement(elementToWaitFor);
    }

    protected WebElement waitUntil(By elementToWaitFor) {
        return this.waitUntil(elementToWaitFor, 45, 1);
    }
}
```

This is how I use the clickATab:

```
    // Expand all closed tabs
    formBuilder.clickATab(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with, the example above helped lead me here.  Posting this in the case others run into a similar problem.  This required a little refactoring in terms of how I identified lists and used them in different methods, but I've been able to remove a ton of wait time, my tests are running much faster now.

I'd appreciate feedback if this could be made more efficient or if I'm doing something wrong.

```
package com.xxx.web_form;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;

abstract class fluentWait {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    FluentWait<WebDriver> fluentWait;

    protected fluentWait(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(this.driver);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected WebElement waitUntil(By elementToWaitFor, int timeout, int pollTimeout) {
        fluentWait.withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        fluentWait.pollingEvery(pollTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        fluentWait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
        fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToWaitFor));
        fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[class='ui active loader loader']")));
        return driver.findElement(elementToWaitFor);
    }

    protected WebElement waitUntil(By elementToWaitFor) {
        return this.waitUntil(elementToWaitFor, 45, 1);
    }

    protected List<WebElement> waitUntilList(final List<WebElement> elementsToWaitFor, Duration interval) { 
        fluentWait.withTimeout(interval); 
        fluentWait.pollingEvery(interval);
        fluentWait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
        fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[class='ui active loader loader']")));
        return (elementsToWaitFor);
    }

    protected List<WebElement> waitUntilList(By elementsToWaitFor) throws InterruptedException {
        // loop until element list value is not 0
        while (driver.findElements(elementsToWaitFor).size() == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (i > 5) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Waiting for list element...");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        return (driver.findElements(elementsToWaitFor));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
protected List<WebElement> waitUntil(By elementToWaitFor, int timeout, int pollTimeout) 
    {
        WebDriver driver = iDriver;
        FluentWait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(this.iDriver);
        fluentWait.withTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        fluentWait.pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        fluentWait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
        fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[class='ui active loader loader']")));

        List<WebElement> list= fluentWait.until(new Function<WebDriver,List<WebElement>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public List<WebElement> apply(WebDriver input) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(elementToWaitFor);

                        if(list.size() > 0)
                            throw new NoSuchElementException("List is not loaded");
                        else
                            return list;
                    }

                });
        return list;
    }
```

PS: I couldn't executed this. I hope it works. If you find any issue, please let me know.

Comment: I was not able to get this example running in my project - just coming back to this now, I do not recall what did not work.